# Mongo: find by ObjectId is not defined in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am using existing Mongodb in meteor project. The existing mongo id represented by `ObjectId()`. When I try to find by `_id`, Meteor says `ObjectId is not defined`

**JS**:

```
Names = new Mongo.Collection('name_list', {idGeneration: 'MONGO'});
Names.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5539d9dcf046be5b2302aefc")}) //ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined
```

The above JavaScript code is run in server.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `new Mongo.ObjectID("5539d9dcf046be5b2302aefc")`. See the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id) for some caveats.

If you want to save having to type `new` and `Mongo.` each time, you can define a function:

```
function ObjectId(hexString) { return new Mongo.ObjectID(hexString); };
```

and then the code you wrote will work.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to require the ObjectId function from your mongo.

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
ObjectId("5539d9dcf046be5b2302aefc")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongojs:

```
db.mycollection.findOne({
    _id: mongojs.ObjectId('your object id')
}, function(err, doc) {
    //do your stuff here.
})
```